# Some Delphi errors

Tags: delphi, oop, delphi-7

I try to make class Ball which should be in Unit and then I need to draw Ball on form with using `Canvas`. Actually I never trying OOP in Delphi before (all I rember is simple exercises in school in Pascal) so I got many problems. Oh. 
So, here the code
unit with Ball class

```
unit Unit2;

interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  MyPoint = record
    x, y: integer;
  end;

  Ball = class
    Pos:MyPoint;
    Vel:MyPoint;
    Rad:integer;
    Can:TCanvas;
    procedure BallCreate(crd, spd:MyPoint; Sender: TObject);
    procedure BallDraw(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BallMove();
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
var
  posX, posY, speedX, speedY, radius:Integer;

implementation
procedure Ball.BallMove;
begin
   if((posX + radius > 700) or (posX - radius  < 0)) then speedX:= (-speedX);
   if((posY + radius > 500) or (posY - radius < 0)) then speedY:= (-speedY);
    posX:=posX+speedX;
    posY:=posY+speedY;
end;

procedure Ball.BallCreate(crd, spd:MyPoint; Sender: TObject);
begin
  Vel.x:=3;
  Vel.y:=3;
  pos.X:=crd.x;
  pos.Y:=crd.y;
  radius:=30;
end;



procedure Ball.BallDraw(Sender: TObject);
begin
with Can do
 begin
  brush.Style:=bsSolid;
  brush.Color:=clRed;
  ellipse((pos.X-radius),(pos.Y-radius),(pos.X+radius),(pos.Y+radius));
 end;
end;

end.
```

unit with Form

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  x1,y1,x2,y2,x,y:integer;
  posX, posY, speedX, speedY, radius:Integer;
  f:boolean;
  obj:Ball;
  p:MyPoint;
  s:MyPoint;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}
{procedure TForm1.BallMove;
begin
   if((posX + radius > ClientWidth) or (posX - radius  < 0)) then speedX:= (-speedX);
   if((posY + radius > ClientHeight) or (posY - radius < 0)) then speedY:= (-speedY);
    posX:=posX+speedX;
    posY:=posY+speedY;
end;              }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled:=false;
  Timer1.Interval:=5;
  p.x:= Round(ClientWidth/2);
  p.y:= Round(ClientHeight/2);
  s.y:=3;
  s.x:=s.y;
  obj.BallCreate(p,s,Sender);

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if not f then
 begin
  Timer1.Enabled:=true;
  Button1.Caption:='Ñòîï';
  f:=not f;
 end
else
 begin
  Timer1.Enabled:=false;
  Button1.Caption:='Ïóñê';
  f:=not f;
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
 obj.BallDraw(Sender);
 obj.BallMove;
end;

end.
```

When I try to Run it it says that

```
raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 0044DE7B in module Project1.exe. Write of address 000000C'
```

and in the code those strokes are highlighted red

*Vel.x:=3;*
and
*with Can do*

I don't understand whats wrong and how i sholud declare and use Canvas here properly. Maybe you've got some examples with OOP stuff in units with Canvas in Delphi?

Comment: "calss" -> You can copy and paste text: mark text with mouse, press ctrl+c, go to where you want it, press ctrl+v

Comment: oh sorry. actually it was error windows where i could not make thing like that so i just decided to type it

Comment: You're declaring a TCanvas variable and trying to use it without ever instantiating it. You need `Can := TCanvas.Create` beforehand. Don't forget to free it when you're done with it. Same for the 'Ball', you need `obj := Ball.Create` before attempting to call 'BallCreate'.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz What can you realistically do with such a canvas? OP needs a TPaintBox.

Comment: @David - I didn't look what the code does, I just browsed it for an obvious AV.

Comment: You asked pretty much the same confused question yesterday. Please don't take what I say next the wrong way. I want to help. Your fundamental problem is that you don't know the most basic facts about Delphi. Attempting to paint and animate are relatively advanced concepts, certainly from where you currently are. You need to find the very most basic tutorial on Delphi and master that. If you aren't prepared to do that, then we cannot help you. If you are learning this at school, surely the classes explained the basics. Consult you course materials again.

Comment: @David Well i study Math in university in Russia. And I've been studying for 3 years. And the proffesor just give us an execrcises. Without any explanation cuz we "old enough for find all this crap wherever we want". I know some OOP basics form Java, but there thing are different. More clearly with thing like Ball myBall = new Ball(x,y,z) or someting.

Comment: @Danil - You're welcome! But please don't disregard David's guide.. :)

Comment: And he gave us this task in monday and tomorrow we need to show it him -_-

Comment: @SertacAkyuz yeah i will try hard!

Comment: @David btw smth like this works without any TPaintBox http://codepaste.ru/11843/

Comment: @DanilGholtsman The form's `OnPaint` is fine. That works too. Paint boxes would typically be used when you wanted to paint only to a sub-region of the form. Form `OnPaint` lets you paint on the entire form surface. The key point is that this is a real `TCanvas` that's attached to the handler for a system paint event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared a Can:TCanvas; variable but it's not created anywhere.

You can use the Main form canvas, for that you should pass it to Ball for exmaple in the Ball constructor like:

```
TBall = class
...
public
constructor Create(crd, spd:MyPoint; ACanvas:TCanvas);
....
implementation
...
constructor TBall.Create(crd, spd:MyPoint; ACanvas:TCanvas);
begin
  Can := ACavas;
...
```

Then, you are not properly creating and instance of Ball:

obj.BallCreate(p,s,Sender);

to create an instance you have to call the class constructor like

```
obj := TBall.Create(crd, spd, Self.Canvas);
```

By the way the "T" before Ball is just a convention to name a class in Delphi